# How exactly does the import machinery work in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

I am new to Node.js, and while learning its basics, I came across some of its import syntax and semantics of the CJS system such as `require()`, `module.exports` and so on.

Now I have quite a few questions related to Node.js internals in this regard, but couldn't find any convincing answers out there, maybe because Node.js is still a relatively recent technology.

Q1) **To achieve a local scope and keep all the global variables in a module private, why does Node.js use a [function to wrap](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_the_module_wrapper) the module's code? Can't this local scope kind-of thing be implemented *without* using functions?**

Q2) **Why are 5 args passed to this wrapper function? Why can't they just be *free variables* of the wrapped function instead of being local to the function?**

Q3) **How does Node.js call this wrapper function?** It seems to be an *anonymous function*, and as far as I know, there is no way to call an anonymous function unless it's saved in an identifier or is immediately invoked.

Q4) **Are all `require()` calls in a module resolved at *compile time* to save computation time, or are they resolved at *runtime*.**

Answer (score 1):

> Q1) To achieve a local scope and keep all the global variables in a module private, why does Node.js use a function to wrap the module's code? Can't this local scope kind-of thing be implemented without using functions?

An execution context of a function is the mechanism to create a local scope in JavaScript. Local variables of a function are unavailable outside of its execution context, unless you return them. The benefit of that is that the global scope doesn't get *polluted* with variables from different files.

> Q2) Why are 5 args passed to this wrapper function? Why can't they just be free variables of the wrapped function instead of being local to the function?

There is a different instance of those 5 args that get passed on each function call.

> Q3) How does Node.js call this wrapper function? It seems to be an anonymous function, and as far as I know, there is no way to call an anonymous function unless it's saved in an identifier or is immediately invoked.

There are multiple steps that happen after invoking `require()`. Regarding your specific question - when `Module.prototype._compile()` is called during the execution of `require('file.js')`, it wraps the contents of `file.js` in a function and then runs that function.

> Q4) Are all require() calls in a module resolved at compile time to
> save computation time, or are they resolved at runtime.

Modules are cached on their first invocation with `require()`. Every time you call `require('file.js')` you get the same instance of `file.js`.

Comment: Well, following from Node's source on GitHub, it seems that module resolution happens at runtime... Am I on the right track? Is this actually the case?

Comment: Yes, `require()` is a function call and is resolved at runtime. This allows for things like lazy-loading, conditional loading, dynamic arguments, etc.